# How can I get next available node in DOM with schema?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xsd, xerces

I need to query the names of "available" sub elements of an element node in DOM.

For example if schema says "There can be age, name, occupation elements under person element." then I wanna function like this,

```
import org.w3c.dom.Element; 

Element person_element;

String[] names_of_available_sub_element = 
         get_available_sub_element_names(person_element);
```

which makes

```
names_of_available_sub_element == {"age", "name", "occupation"}.
```

How can I implement this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't easy, but it can be done if you're prepared to put a lot of work in.

There are a number of approaches to getting information from an XSD schema. You could try and process the XSD source code, but I wouldn't recommend that, because there are so many things you have to take into account (wildcards, substitution groups, types derived by restriction and extension, and so on). A better approach is to use some kind of API that gives you access to the information in digested form. For that, some possible suggestions are:

(a) Xerces gives you a Java API providing programmatic access to the compiled schema.

(b) Saxon gives you two possibilities: (i) the SCM file, which is an XML representation of the compiled schema, and (ii) an XPath API giving programmatic access to the compiled schema using extension functions.

Do remember that knowing you're at a "person" element isn't (in the general case) enough to determine what the permitted children are. That's because there can be global and local elements using the name "person", but with different types. Whether this is a problem in your case depends on what you are trying to achieve, which you haven't really explained in much detail.